# Proc Sql - Same column name from 3 tables and manipulate

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

Here is the example data.

Table1:

```
iD Flag  Reason
1    1     ABCD
2    0     
3    0     
4    1     ERS
5    0
```

Table2:

```
iD Flag  Reason
1    1     ERS
2    1     FGH
3    1     DDD
4    1     
5    0
```

Table3:

```
iD Flag  Reason
1    1     
2    1    DDD
3    1     
4    1     
5    1    ERS
```

I am trying to write a proc sql that will help me separate the different reason case scenario.

```
proc sql;
select case when (table1.flag = 1 and reason = 'ABCD') then 1
        when (table2.flag = 1 and reason = 'ABCD') then 1
        when (table3.flag = 1 and reason = 'ABCD') then 1
        when (table1.flag = 1 and reason = 'FGH') then 2
        when (table2.flag = 1 and reason = 'FGH') then 2
          :
          :
        when (table3.flag = 1 and reason = 'ERS') then 4
        Else 0
        End as output
   from table1
   inner join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
   inner join table3 on table1.id = table3.id
   ;
```

Here is the output I am trying to get,

```
 Id Reason Output 
 1  ABCD     1
 2  FGH      2
 3  DDD      3 
 4  ERS      4
 5  ERS      4
```

Even though, the reason might change in different tables for the same id, i need the first occurring reason in any of the table based on the Flag variable and assign the output.

Is there any other way to do the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is probably a better way.  Can you explain the logic more clearly?  For instance, your desired output has three columns, but the sample code only produces one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query produces the output that you are looking for:

```
select t1.id,
       (case when t1.flag = 1 then t1.reason
             when t2.flag = 1 then t2.reason
             when t3.flag = 1 then t3.reason
        end) as reason,
       (case when calculated reason = 'ABCD' then 1
             when calculated reason = 'FGH' then 2
             when calculated reason = 'DDD' then 3
             when calculated reason = 'FGH' then 4
             else 0
        end) as output
from table1 t1 inner join
     table2 t2 
     on t1.id = t2.id inner join
     table3 t3
     on t1.id = t3.id;
```

Note the use of the `calculated` keyword.  This is a nice feature in `proc sql` that makes it unnecessary to use a subquery or repeated the defining expression.